# How to position two divs next to each that expand to the size available without wrapping

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

Consider this bit of HTML & CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Relative Positioning Resize Demo</title>
        <style>
            div.outerDiv {
                border: 1px solid black;
                height: 300px;
                padding: 10px;
            }

            div.innerDivA, div.innerDivB {
                border: 1px solid blue;
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
            }

            div.innerDivB {
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDivA">content a</div>
            <div class="innerDivB">content b</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The outer div does not have a width specified and expands to the width of the browser window. I want the inner divs to behave similarly, expanding to the width available within their parent div while respecting the 10px margin and padding, never wrapping to two lines, and adjusting to the resizing of the browser window. I've tinkered with relative widths and haven't really achieved the results I'm looking for.

Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: oh, and the borders, of course. That's one thing that seemed to be throwing off relative widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desire for minimal markup is understandable, but mixing and matching percentages and specific pixel values with the various box models will **not** guarantee consistent results with how you have your present structure.

You can do this one of several ways:

1) Add more HTML markup; Fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/kgosser/d4Q2D/

2) Be comfortable with the chance of layout breaking if page size dips below a certain width, such as 400px

3) Do everything with percentages and be comfortable with the paddings being dynamic; Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgosser/EnSd2/

4) Use jquery to dynamically adjust the widths, heights, and margins--specifically using absolute and relative positioning.

Comment: I did consider going the jquery route, it just felt somewhat convoluted. 2 is fine of course, especially if you employ a min-width, but for reasons I won't get into that's not suitable in my case. 1 and 3 are good answers, and 1 is very close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but I think you're running into problems because you're mixing percentage's and pixel values in the CSS. I changed the margin-left to a percentage value and it seems to be behaving a bit better.

**Fiddle Be Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/QkSUN/1/

Comment: This is the approach I tried at first. It's pretty close, but as you say, mixing pixels and percentages makes for some unpredictable results. Another issue is that the margin between the outer div and box B is always a little bigger... it's difficult to make all three margin areas consistently sized the same.

Comment: It's very difficult. You might have to dig into Ethan Marcotte's Responsive Web Design book to get the proper formula for calculating the exact margin you need. It will likely be some absurd number like margin-left: 1.1123234%; or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just check will this solve your problem

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Relative Positioning Resize Demo</title>
    <style>
        div.outerDiv {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        div.innerDivA, div.innerDivB {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
        }
        div.innerDivB {
            margin-left: 10px; width: 48%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outerDiv">
        <div class="innerDivA">content a</div>
        <div class="innerDivB">content b</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nope, divs wrap as the window is resized smaller.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
        div.outerDiv {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        div.innerDivA, div.innerDivB {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            float: left;
            width: 49%;
        }

        div.innerDivB {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

or replace the last style with:

```
       div.innerDivA {
            margin-right: 0.5%;
        }
        div.innerDivB {
            margin-left: 0.5%;
        }
```

Comment: The div's end up stacked when the screen size drops: http://jsfiddle.net/QkSUN/3/

Comment: That does help, but as screen size shrinks they do wrap.

Comment: This would be the best option if you intend on keeping margin as a fixed pixel size or you could use % instead.